# JQuery Mobile Make Buttons Taller

Tags: android, user-interface, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make buttons in JQuery Mobile that are around 5 times taller than the usual button without adding thickness.

So of course I have the usual link as a button code of:   and what do I need to add?

Also how would I center the text in the middle of these buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Preview: http://jsbin.com/ikuvav/

Code: http://jsbin.com/ikuvav/edit

Just add some custom css overriding the button's css

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 5em 20px;
}
```